# connect to remote mysql server via command line in windows

Tags: mysql, windows

I need to connect remote mysql database from my windows machine using command line.
I tried with the following syntax
mysql -h hostname -u username -pPassword mydb
but it does not show up any error not connected

Answer (score 1):

To access the remote mysql server you will need to add your IP address in the grant list of mysql.

Here is a link i used previously and worked for me. 
https://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely

Comment: @Jitesh You should also look through some comments in that page.

Comment: The link is broken